# x-editable for yii doesn't make me edit a field

Tags: php, yii, jeditable

I installed the extension x-editable-yii and I'm trying to use it. It seems relatively simple:

```
<?php
$modelPersoonHasStdTaak = PersoonHasStdTaak::model()->findByPk(array('idPersoon' => 5, 'idPlanning' => 5, 'idStdActiviteit' => 4, 'idStdTaak' => 7));

echo $this->widget('editable.EditableField', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'model' => $modelPersoonHasStdTaak,
    'attribute' => 'idPersoon0',
    'url' => $this->createUrl('persoonhasstdtaak/updatepersoonhasstdtaak'),
    'source' => CHtml::listData(Persoon::model()->findAll(), 'idPersoon', 'Naam'),
    'placement' => 'right',
        ), true);
?>
```

`PersoonHasStdTaak` is a scheduling rule which contains `idPerson` as variable and PK(`idSchedule`,`idStdActivity`,`idTask`) (translated to English).

What It should show is an editable field as shown http://x-editable.demopage.ru/index.php?r=site/widgets#EditableField (number 3: `Select`).

I made the attribute for idPerson `safe` in the `rules()` but still:

```
The output is nothing but one line with a name. NOT the supposed editable field
```

How to make this properly working?

Comment: You're right. X-editable is pretty simple to use. Did you set it up properly in config/main.php ?

Comment: This post doesn't apply enymore I guess, since I've got it fixed long ago, but I'm not really sure what seems to be wrong here ;) So I'm closing the question. Edit: Hmm cannot close with reason: 'Own question, already solved' or something like that...

Comment: @Highmastdon mind sharing your solution?

Comment: @user2636556 It's been a long time... I think it had something to do with the combined Primary Key. I think it should work with newer versions of `x-editable` as it's been updated back then with a patch.

Comment: @Highmastdon i see. well even when i hard code the source i still cant get it to work. ;( posted here too `https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable-yii/issues/129`